# How to change Ammonite, coursier cache location?

Tags: scala, ivy, ammonite, coursier

I am using Coursier in ammonite to download jar from a private repo. However for reason of integration with Intellij, I would like to change the location that coursier uses to cache the artificat. I would like to point to my local ivy. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless Ammonite explicitly sets the cache location via the Coursier API you should be able to set it using the `COURSIER_CACHE` environment variable. See the respective documentation of the [Coursier cache](https://github.com/coursier/coursier/blob/master/doc/docs/cache.md) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering however If i am getting right. Is the coursier cache compatible with an ivy cache ? Will coursier detect that it is an ivy folder and cache accordingly vs a m2 folder for example ?

Comment: I don't think those caches are compatible but wouldn't know for sure.

Comment: I think I need to better understand why in the case of ammonite, IntelliJ can only resolve the declared dependency but not the transitive one. It is rather strange ... is it a cache format issue, is there something particular about sbt that IntelliJ can read ? Or is it at the cache description level ...